# iOS: change png in a bar button item

Tags: ios, xcode, png, uibarbuttonitem

I put in a tolbar a bar button item, and I set it with a png (first.png) and when I push it I want to change its png in "second.png"

This code doesn't work fine:

```
UIImage *first = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];
UIImage *second = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"];

if ([sender isSelected]) 
{  
    [sender setImage:first forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    [sender setSelected:NO];  

}
else 
{     
    [sender setImage:second forState:UIControlStateSelected]; 
    [sender setSelected:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current answerers do not realize that `UIBarButtonItem` does NOT inherit from UIButton, so `setImage:forState:` will most definitely *not* work. UIBarButtonItems *cannot* be set for different states. You *can*, however, utilize something like this (declared in the [UIBarItem docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem)):

```
sender.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write after creation of button this lines:

```
UIImage *first = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];
UIImage *second = [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"];

[sender setImage:first forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sender setImage:second forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

You don't need if-else statement.

Updated:

```
CGRect myFrame;
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
[myButton release];
```

Comment: I have this eror Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a3cc60'

Comment: Different states are declared only for `UIButton`. Create `UIBarButtonItem` with custom `view == UIButton`. Then call this methods to that `UIButton` object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on why you have an if block in there. Can't you initialize both state images as a one-off initialization step? I.e.

```
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

In fact, this can probably be done in Interface Builder if you don't need to do it programmatically.

Comment: I have this eror Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIBarButtonItem setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a3cc60'

Comment: Normally you'd do this kind of initialization in your view controller's `viewDidLoad`. What method did you copy your code snippet from?